# If it is Possible to allow only certain text in input box in JQuery keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, keypress

If it Possible to allow specific string in input box in keyPress event in same order.Important thing is i need to allow only in the same order.

Example:If I need to allow "NILL" user must enter in the same order.If user enter "NL" then we need to restrict them.If it possible.

I've tried the following:

```js
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    var chr = chr = e.key;
    if ("NILL".indexOf(chr) < 0 && e.which != 13)
        return false;
        console.log('allowed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="foo" />
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you already tried?

Comment: I Edit my code in the question.(Added the code)Please check now

Comment: use `chr = e.key` to get the key value as a character

Comment: @CalvinNunes Updated

Comment: I Not Sure what's Wrong in this Question for getting more downvotes. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the string into an array of chars then check each index if it matches the key entered

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var restriction = "NILL";
restriction = restriction.split(''); // transform to array of char
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    var chr = e.key.toUpperCase();
    if(restriction[$(this).val().length] != chr){
    return false;
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="foo" />
```

Comment: Thanks,It Working :)